# Prove $5^n > n^5 $ for $n≥6$

Tags: induction

How can I prove
$5^n > n^5 $ for $n≥ 6  $
using mathematical induction ?

So my solution is

***Step 1***: For $n = 6$
$5^6 = 15625$, $6^5 = 7776$
then $5^n > n^5 $ is true for $n = 6  $

***Step 2***: Assume it's true for $n = k$,  $5^k > k^5 $

***Step 3***: Prove it's true for $n = k+1$
$5^{k+1} > (k+1)^5 $

Here when things get messy I don't know how to prove it for $n = k+1$

Comment: $5^{k+1}=5\times 5^k>5k^5$ by induction hypothesis. If you can show that $5k^5\ge (k+1)^5$ for $k\ge 6$, you're done!

Comment: For $k\ge 6$ you have $5>(7/6)^5\ge (k+1)^5/k^5$, so you get $5k^5>(k+1)^5$. That ends the proof of @Taladris

Comment: @TomKeen: how do you show that $5>(7/6)^5$? It is not obvious to me

Comment: @Taladris by seeing $5\cdot 6^5>7^5$ via simple computation

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to consider the function $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ for $x>0$ and discuss its maximum and monotonicity. The answer should be as follows.

1. When $0<x<e$, the function $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is increasing.
2. When $x>e$, the function $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is decreasing.

From these conclusions, the inequality $5^n>n^5$, which is equivalent to $\frac{\ln5}{5}>\frac{\ln n}{n}$, for $n\ge6$ is derived immediately.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(n): 5^n > n^5   \text{  :   } \forall n \ge6$$

- Base Case: $5^6 >6^5$ is True
- Inductive Case:$P(k)\implies P(k+1)$

*The induction step, proves that if the statement holds for any given case $n = k$, then it must also hold for the next case $n = k + 1$. These two steps establish that the statement holds for every natural number $n$. The base case does not necessarily begin with $n = 0$, but often with $n = 1$, and possibly with any fixed natural number $n = N$(here, $N = 6$), establishing the truth of the statement for all natural numbers $n\ge N.$*

$$\color{blue}{P(k): 5^k > k^5 \implies  (5^k5 = 5^{k +1})>5k^5} $$

To prove $P(k+1) $ is true we need to prove $(5^{k+1} = \color{blue}{5^k.5  > 5k^5} )> (k+1)^5$

Now,
$\color{blue}{1< 5k < 10k^2 < 10k^3< 5k^4}$ is true for $k\ge3 \implies \forall k\ge6$ *You can prove this by considering that $P(1<n<5)$ is not true but we know this is obvious.*

$k^4 = k^4 \implies \color{red}{5k^4 = 5k^4} \text{ for } (k\ge 1 \implies \text{ also true for } k\ge 6)$

Consider  $\color{red}{5k^4 = 5k^4}$ for $k> 5$ We have $\color{blue}{5k^4 \le \color{green}k\times k^4} \text{As } k> 5 $

Combining the above results we have
$\color{blue}{1< 5k < 10k^2 < 10k^3< 5k^4 < k^5} \text{ is true for} k > 5 \implies \text{ also true for } k > 6$

$$\begin{align*}
(k+1)^5 
& = k^5 + 5k^4 + 10k^3 + 10k^2 + 5k + 1\\
& < k^5 + k^5 + k^5 + k^5 + k^5 = 5k^5 < 5^{k+1}
\text{thus } P(k + 1) \text{is True}
\end{align*}$$

Now, if True of $P(k)$ $\implies $ True of $P(k+ 1) $ for $k> 6$ then $P(N>6) $ is True.

Comment: You looked for *proof by induction* maybe I'm bad at that however, $\frac {\ln 5}5  > \frac {\ln n} n$ is easier way as $O(n) > O(\ln n ) $ also regardless of all other facts you can prove by differentiating $f(n)$ which is monotonic from point $n = 5$